# jParser.makeHttpRequest wont catch error when I'm not connected to internet

Tags: android, json

I'm developing an application that connects to a PHP and get data from database.

My problem is when I get data by `jParser.makeHttpRequest` with internet connection and close my internet and do that again `jParser.makeHttpRequest` returns the last thing that it returned. It won't give No Internet Error or sοmething like that. How can I correct this?

```
jParser = new JSONParser();
JSONObject json = jParser.makeHttpRequest(url_get_login_infos, "GET", _params);
int success = json.getInt(TAG_SUCCESS);
String message = json.getString(TAG_MESSAGE);
```

Answer (score 0):

Object are destroy by garbage collector. Your object still exists when you call data for the second time. 
Reset your parser with null for example before you call data and test the result. Post your some code  for more answers

here some of code with Json wich works fine

```
     protected String doInBackground(String... args) {

        //affectation des valeurs pour passage à PHP
        String email = getEmail();

        // Building Parameters
        List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("email", email));

        // getting JSON Object
        String url = SingletonParametres.getUrlConnexion() + "get_selectuser.php";
        JSONObject json = null;
        try {
            json = jsonParser.makeHttpRequest(url, "GET", params);
        } catch (HttpException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        // check for success tag
        try {
            String Variablepourvoir = json.getString(TAG_SUCCESS);
            success = json.getInt(TAG_SUCCESS);
            switch (success) {
                case 1: {              /* user retrouvé avec succes */
                    // successfully select user
                    setCodeRetour(1);
                    setMsgRetour("user existe MyApplication ok");
                    // sauvegarde des données User dans la classApplication
                    // successfully received product details
                    JSONArray JsonUserArray = json.getJSONArray("user"); // JSON Array

                    // get first user object from JSON Array
                    JSONObject JsonUserObject = JsonUserArray.getJSONObject(0);

                    // user with this email found
                    //save data in MyApplication

                    MyApplication.setIdUser(JsonUserObject.getInt("iduser"));
                    MyApplication.setEmail(JsonUserObject.getString("email"));
                    MyApplication.setPseudo(JsonUserObject.getString("pseudo"));
                    if ( JsonUserObject.getInt("autorisation_upload") ==1 ) {
                        MyApplication.setAutorisationUpload(true);
                    } else {
                        MyApplication.setAutorisationUpload(false);
                    }

                        break;
                }
                case 0: {              /* oops ! ... un probleme est survenu */
                    setCodeRetour(ECHEC);
                    setMsgRetour("user non trouvé MyApplication echec");
                    break;

                }
            }



        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return null;
    }
```

Comment: I put jParser = new JSONParser(); just before jParser.makeHttpRequest but same thing happened

Comment: Witch value is in your TAG_SUCCESS ? Why don t you test it ? when you said "returns the last thing that it returned" or "same thing happened" what did you mean by that ?

Comment: when I try to catch HttpException AndroidStudio says Exception 'org.apache.http.HttpException' is never thrown in the corresponding try block.

Comment: private static final String TAG_SUCCESS = "success"; I have tested it with Log.d, I checked which value I'm getting from php and it was correct when I was connected to internet. I mean by "returns the last thing that it returned" is json stays the same when I tried to connect without internet connection.

Comment: don t you have a "throws exception" in method ? something like  public void yourmethod() throws HttpException { ... } ? please show me your real code or i won t be able to help you

Answer (score 0):

try this, you have that add this condition:

```
    if(json != null){
    //excecute code

    }else{
        getActivity().runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "conection error", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
           }
         });
}
```

This way of writing the Toast, is if you work in a Fragment.

in your code, make this:

```
String url = SingletonParametres.getUrlConnexion() + "get_selectuser.php";
JSONObject json = null;
json = jsonParser.makeHttpRequest(url, "GET", params);
if(json != null) {

    try {
            String Variablepourvoir = json.getString(TAG_SUCCESS);
            success = json.getInt(TAG_SUCCESS);
            switch (success) {
                case 1: { 

           .....
           .....
}else{
    getActivity().runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "conection error", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
       }
     });
}
```